# The Vanishing point in Solidworks is reversed in my install...Is there a fix?

Tags: solidworks

Somehow, the vanishing point has been negated in my version of solidworks... Ie, a block, when rotated, expands in the distance and shrinks up close.  Ergo, there has been a minus sign added to the vanishing point in code.

I'm using a version of solidworks on a University network, so obviously, it is possible that some toolbag switched it up...

Is there an easy way to fix it in the settings or something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking at a perspective view? You can change the perspective amount.